# Add Card to google pay issue

Tags: android, google-play-services

While integrating Add Card to Google pay from our app using TapAndPay Sdk v18.3.2. When tried to call push tokenization request with OPC and user address, it shows error message Something went wrong. Trying to get the Android logcat, it's showing TanAndPayApiException Error.

Wanted to know how we can proceed further with this issue.

Comment: Can you provide more logs from that exception? It could be due to a variety of issues.